# Considerations for developing for a VM deployment

Tags: deployment, virtual-machine

I'm setting up a system that uses SQL Server 2005, several custom Windows Services, Web Services and a few IIS .NET applications.  Getting the whole system setup is a somewhat tedious process.

I wondered whether it would be a good idea to settup the whole system in a VM.  Could I then just drop the VM onto a new server and get a huge headstart on configuration?

What things should I be aware of if I pursue this approach?  Is it a viable option?  Is a VM a decent unit of deployment?

If the concept is feasible, I'd certainly appreciate specific suggestions about the VM setup.

Answer (score 1):

I frequently use this approach. I'll set up a VM in VMware Workstation, configure it to my liking, and then use VMware Importer to import my virtual machine into an ESX environment. From there, I can turn the virtual machine into a template that I can use over and over again for deploying clones of my server or just as a starting point when creating new servers.

Comment: None that I'm aware of, or have run into. One thing you'll want to be aware of, though, is that if you're creating Windows VMs, you'll probably want to wait to join to a domain until after you deploy. Running NewSID is also recommended with Windows servers once deployed.

Answer (score 0):

· Large quantity of virtual machines (one for each customer)
· Less quantity of physical machines
· VM's we are working on has to be up while the others can be down
· Easy backups so, in case of issues we can start working on the same moment we shut down the vm, etc...
· Physical machines has to configured with the last hardware or almost.
· Depending on your develops, a physical machine can keep between 4 and 8 VM.